# How can we get pointers' location from ELF binary or from metadata generated from compiler

Tags: linux, pointers, compiler-construction, llvm, elf

Is there a way to examine the `.data` and `.bss` sections in an ELF binary to figure out which bytes are pointers? Or is there a way to leverage compiler (e.g., an LLVM pass) to generate such information?

Comment: Variable types are in the debugging information. So find all the global pointer variables, then get their locations.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit clear? Do you mean DWARF? I tried to look at `objdump --dwarf=info ./a.out`, it is quite complicated. Is there any useful reference I can look at? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the details. That's how debuggers do it, so if you want to write similar code you need to study the references.

Comment: @xiaogw What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Looking at DWARF variables and types will tell you about (most of) the pointers that are also present in the source code, looking at ELF fixups will tell you about the pointers that are already initialised to point to other parts of the executable or libraries. You should be able to get a complete-enough picture, but it won't be simple.

Comment: I was trying to do a research project moving code around at runtime.@EmployedRussian